# MFC Ribbon quick access toolbar crash when state is changed

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an old MFC application I am updating and I just added a ribbon (using the `CMFCRibbonBar` class).

However any commands in the quick access toolbar on the ribbon that cause a change in state (eg closing the file and exiting to the main menu) cause a crash when the command is used from the quick access toolbar but not the normal ribbon button.

The crash happens in the MFC file `afxribbonbar.cpp` in `OnMouseMove()`

```
if (pHit != m_pHighlighted)
    {
        PopTooltip();

        if (m_pHighlighted != NULL)
        {
            ASSERT_VALID(m_pHighlighted);
            m_pHighlighted->m_bIsHighlighted = FALSE;
            m_pHighlighted->OnHighlight(FALSE);

            InvalidateRect(m_pHighlighted->GetRect());

            m_pHighlighted = NULL;
        }
```

It crashes on the `InvalidateRect` line, because `m_pHighlighted` seems to exist but have no data, so either the stack is corrupted or `m_pHighlighted` doesn't exist anymore.

I have some lines to reload where all the frames were last time the user was in the new state and I found if I comment out the lines when I change state the crash doesn't happen:

```
theApp.SaveState(this, ToolbarKey(i_oldAppState));
```

and

```
theApp.LoadState( this, ToolbarKey(i_newAppState) );
```

But ideally I want these lines as otherwise all the windows and frames revert to their default state and users have to resize everything again.

It feels like the entries in the quick access toolbar are being destroyed and recreated when I change state, but I can't find where MFC does this, or a way to set the highlighted entry to null.

EDIT: The crash is an unhandled exception due to an access reading violation in mfc140u.dll. The crash happens deep in the MFC code, well away from anything I have written.

The call stack when this unhandled exception occurs is:

```
  mfc140u.dll!CBasePane::get_accValue(tagVARIANT varChild, wchar_t * * pszValue) Line 1494 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CMFCRibbonBar::OnMouseMove(unsigned int nFlags, CPoint point) Line 2348 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CMFCRibbonBar::OnLButtonUp(unsigned int nFlags, CPoint point) Line 2276 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam, __int64 * pResult) Line 2698 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 2099 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CBasePane::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 1020 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CMFCRibbonBar::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 4884 C++
  mfc140u.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 265 C++
  mfc140u.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 417 C++
  mfc140u.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 299 C++
  user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow() Unknown
  user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker() Unknown
  user32.dll!IsDialogMessageW() Unknown
  mfc140u.dll!CWnd::IsDialogMessageW(tagMSG * lpMsg) Line 194 C++
  [Inline Frame] mfc140u.dll!CWnd::PreTranslateInput(tagMSG *) Line 4606 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CBasePane::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 1057 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CMFCRibbonBar::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 3734 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CWnd::WalkPreTranslateTree(HWND__ * hWndStop, tagMSG * pMsg) Line 3379 C++
  mfc140u.dll!AfxInternalPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 233 C++
  mfc140u.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage() Line 178 C++
  mfc140u.dll!CWinThread::Run() Line 629 C++
```

Comment: From where you got that m_pHighlighted? Can you set it to null before you do LoadState?

Comment: *"It crashes"* - That's a very generic phrase, and lots of people attribute lots of different semantics to what a *"crash"* is. Does the program terminate due to an uncaught exception? Does it terminate in response to an SEH exception. Or are you seeing a [failed debug assertion dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/assertion-failed-dialog-box) instead, which doesn't actually crash.

Comment: To that memory content m_pHighlighted points to? all bytes 0xdd? Than the old storage was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug in the BCG Library. I Made my private fix there for the variables m_pHighlighted and m_pPressed.

```
BOOL CBCGPRibbonBar::LoadState (LPCTSTR lpszProfileName, int nIndex, UINT uiID)
{
// 2014-04-23 mri: we need to clear pointer to may be active elements that
// may get deleted, when LoadState is executed.
// We cannot set m_pActiveCategory to NULL!!!! This get us into problems when the
// program starts and the minimize/maximize button is used, when this pointer is 
// NULL. 
    m_pHighlighted = NULL;
    m_pPressed = NULL;
```

You should set them to `nullptr` before you call LoadState

As I remember the problem ist that a click in the ribbon is handled in the Mouse-Down message. So the Mouse-Up message is never executed that clears this member...

Comment: Thank you so much. This appears to be the fix. So obvious in hindsight. I guess I thought the MFC library would be smarter than that.